# Adding an element from a list before and after the delimiter of another list

Tags: python, list

There are 2 lists and my goal is to add the element from one list before and after the delimiters of another list.
Below is the example:

```py
ListA = ["A", "B"]
ListB = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Expected Output:

```
[[1, 'A', 2, 'A', 3, 'A', 4, 'A'], [5, 'B', 6, 'B', 7, 'B', 8, 'B']]
```

What I've done so far:

```py
for x, y in zip(ListB, ListA):
    x.append(y)
```

Output: ListB

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 'A'], [5, 6, 7, 8, 'B']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appends 'A' once to the whole [1,2,3,4] list.
This should work:

```
ListA = ['A','B']
ListB = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]

for x, y in zip(ListB, ListA):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x.insert(2*i+1,y)

print(ListB)
# [[1, 'A', 2, 'A', 3, 'A', 4, 'A'], [5, 'B', 6, 'B', 7, 'B', 8, 'B']]
```

A variant to produce something closest to your 2nd demand:

```
ListA = ['A','B','C'] 
ListB = [[1,5],[2,10],[11,15]]
for x, y in zip(ListB, ListA):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i] = y + ' ' + str(x[i])

print(ListB)
# [['A 1', 'A 5'], ['B 2', 'B 10'], ['C 11', 'C 15']]
```

Comment: There is a modification to the above question here
`
ListA = ['A','B','C']
ListB = [[1,5],[2,10],[11,15]

Expected Output : ListB : [['A' 1,'A' 5],['B' 2,'B' 10],['C' 11, 'C' 15]]
`

Comment: For this, just replace 2*i+1 with 2*i in the code.

Comment: yes I tried that but  its appending with commas. Here's the output I got by replacing  2*i+1 with 2*i. I think something else needs to be used here instead of insert but not able to figure it out
Output : [['A', 1, 'A', 5], ['B', 2, 'B', 10], ['C', 11, 'C', 15]]

Comment: I didn't read your previous comment carefully enough. That said, 'A' 1 is not acceptable Python syntax! 'A 1' would be.

Comment: I made a mistake there, the expected output should look like :
 [['A 1,'A 5'],['B 2','B 10'],['C 11', 'C 15']]

Answer (score 0):

`zip` the two lists together, and then build new lists out of pairs of all the `b` items with the single `a` item:

```
>>> ListA = ['A','B']
>>> ListB = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
>>> [[j for t in ((i, a) for i in b) for j in t] for a, b in zip(ListA, ListB)]
[[1, 'A', 2, 'A', 3, 'A', 4, 'A'], [5, 'B', 6, 'B', 7, 'B', 8, 'B']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach to this:

```py
from itertools import repeat

ListA = ["A", "B"]
ListB = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]

result = []
for x, y in zip(ListA, ListB):
    nested_list = []
    for item in zip(y, repeat(x)):
        nested_list.extend(item)
    result.append(nested_list)

print(result)
```

This can be written using a bit more complex list comp(Also this modifies `ListB` in-place instead of creating a new one):

```py
from itertools import repeat

ListA = ["A", "B"]
ListB = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]

ListB[:] = [
    [i for item in zip(y, repeat(x)) for i in item] for x, y in zip(ListA, ListB)
]
print(ListB)
```